# can a DELL R610 DRAC been configured while Linux OS running?

Tags: linux, dell, drac

I've a Dell R610 server up and running with RHEL5, with not much possibility of getting a reboot in the near future. The DRAC card was not setup in BIOS on the initial install.

My question is there any way I can configure the DRAC to get on the network without rebooting and going to BIOS ?

I've tried the dell racadm rpms but they cannot find the DRAC card, saying  "RACADM is unable to process the request because there is no local RAC config to communicate with" I'm not sure if this message is because it was not configured at install time via the BIOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which `racadm` command are you using?

Dell says:

Run the racadm command from `/opt/dell/srvadmin/rac5/bin/racadm` if you have one of the following systems: PowerEdge 2950-iii, PowerEdge 1950-iii, PowerEdge 2900-iii, PowerEdge R805, PowerEdge R900 or PowerEdge R905.

Run the racadm command from `/opt/dell/srvadmin/idrac/bin/racadm` if you have one of the following systems: PowerEdge M600, PowerEdge M605, PowerEdge M805, PowerEdge M905, PowerEdge R710, PowerEdge R610, PowerEdge T610, PowerEdge T710, PowerEdge M610 or PowerEdge M710.

See: http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/Citrix/EN/SolutionsGuide/5_5/HTML/solutioi.htm#wp1183031

Comment: Ahh that could be my issue , its a R610 and I dont have an /opt/dell/srvadmin/idrac dir . I will go and try to find the idrac binaries. Cheers

Comment: How did you install the idrac software/drivers? Try this link: http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/OMSA

Comment: I found the full srvadm suite on the Dell DVD that came with the server. I installed the packages and the correct idrac software was installed. I must have installed the wrong package 1st time round.